# Can I get some sort of notification from parse.com if a user "flags" certain material from my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, parse-platform, spam-prevention

I am using parse.com to store my backend.  My data is crowd sourced.  So there is a chance that some material will be vulgar/spam.  I want to allow the user to flag certain objects that I store in Parse so I/others can take a look at it.  My idea right now is to have the user tap a button on the object in question and have that send me an email.  I don't believe I can have that send me an email with some reference to that object.  I know I can have the email UI pop up and they can send it that way, and that will be my last resort.  But is there a way I can utilize parse and just have that button tap send some data to my parse backend, then have that send me an email with that object id in the email?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Parse's Cloud Module Guide. It has instructions on how you can use SendGrid, Mailgun, or Mandrill from cloud code to send an email whenever a new object is saved. You can use this to send yourself an email when a user creates a new "Flag".